# How to find continuous segment pair in given list of integers (Functionally not imerative)?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I have List of integers like {1,2,3,5,8,9,10}, I need the following result
[1,3],[5,5],[8,10]

I written the solution using imperative style, but I want a solution which align with functional programming.

My imperative solution:

```
    public static List<ContinuousNotificationSegment> ConvertToNotificationSegment(this List<NotificationDTO> input)
    {
        var sortedNotificationList = input.Select(n => n.ID).ToList();
        sortedNotificationList = sortedNotificationList.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
        List<ContinuousNotificationSegment> continuousSegments = new List<ContinuousNotificationSegment>();

        long continuousSegmentStart = 0, continuousSegmentEnd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedNotificationList.Count; i++)
        {                
            if (IsContinuous(sortedNotificationList[i], ((i + 1) < sortedNotificationList.Count ? sortedNotificationList[i + 1] : -999)))
            {
                continuousSegmentStart = continuousSegmentStart == 0 ? sortedNotificationList[i] : continuousSegmentStart;
            }
            else
            {
                continuousSegmentEnd = sortedNotificationList[i];

                continuousSegments.Add(new ContinuousNotificationSegment
                {
                    MinNotificationId = continuousSegmentStart == 0 ? continuousSegmentEnd : continuousSegmentStart,
                    MaxNotificationId = continuousSegmentEnd
                });

                continuousSegmentStart = 0;
            }
        }

        return continuousSegments;
    }

    private static bool IsContinuous(long prevValue, long nextValue)
    {
        return nextValue - prevValue == 1;
    }
```

Comment: What's the rules behind converting `{1,2,3,5,8,9,10}`, to the result `[1,3],[5,5],[8,10]`?

Comment: @DavidArno Looks like ranges based on consecutive numbers being no more than 1 greater than the previous numbers in the ordered list.

Comment: @DavidArno It's a list of ranges of consecutive integers.

Comment: @Mohanraja - Then how did you try to change it? There is not real question here besides - "please program it for me in a "functional programming" way"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10 };

var result =
    input
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            input.Take(1).Select(x => new { start = x, end = x }).ToList(),
            (a, x) =>
            {
                var last = a.Last();
                if (last.end + 1 == x)
                {
                    a[a.Count - 1] = new { start = last.start, end = x };
                }
                else
                {
                    a.Add(new { start = x, end = x });
                }
                return a;
            });
```

That works. I get:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by first ordering the list of numbers, then selecting the number and a grouping id that is incremented when the difference between the current number and the previous is greater than 1.  Then just group on that grouping id and take the min and max numbers as the range.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Runs(this IEnumerable<int> nums)
{
    int? prev = null;
    int group = 0;
    return nums.OrderBy(n => n)
        .Select(
            n =>
            {
                if (prev.HasValue && n - prev.Value > 1) { group++; }
                prev = n;
                return new { group, num = n };
            })
        .GroupBy(x => x.group)
        .Select(g => new Tuple<int, int>(g.Min(x => x.num), g.Max(x => x.num)));
}
```

And this code

```
var nums = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(";", nums.Runs()));
```

Outputs

> (1, 3);(5, 5);(7, 9)

Answer (score 1):

As I've been teached to program functionally it should look like (warning, it's [pseudocode]! and [tail recursion]!)

```
GetRanges(input)
    if (input == null || input.Count == 0) 
        return {};

    var ranges = {};
    GetRangesInternal(ranges, {null, null}, input);
    return ranges;

GetRangesInternal(ranges, {initialElement, lastElement}, input) =>
    var head = input.Take(1);
    var tail = input.Skip(1);

    // no first element - prepare new range and move on
    if (initialElement == null)
        GetRangesInternal(ranges, {head, head}, tail);
        return;

    // range continued - update it and move on
    if (head == lastElement+1)
        GetRangesInternal(ranges, {initialElement, head}, tail)
        return;

    // range stopped - add it to result
    ranges.Add({initialElement, lastElement});
    GetRangesInternal(ranges, {head, head}, tail);
```

`GetRanges` is entry point

Answer (score 0):

The most compact and clear LINQ I could come up with is this:

```
var intList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10 };

var agg = intList.Aggregate(new List<List<int>> { new List<int>() }, (i, j) =>
    {
        if (!i.Last().Any() || i.Last().Last() + 1 == j)
            i.Last().Add(j);
        else
            i.Add(new List<int> { j });
        return i;
    }).Select(i => new List<int> { i.First(), i.Last() });
```

The result is exactly as described in the question.